# Jquery dropdown menu onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a simple dropdown menu with jquery but I cant seem to get any of the javascript to work. I have tried calling it externally. I am not sure what the problem can be, if you see a problem please let me know. Thanks.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    #container{width:978px;}
    .content {
        display: none;
        padding-left: 5px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        top: 30px;
        background: yellow;
    }
    ul{width: 100%;}
    li{
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
        background: #e5e5e5;}

    #div{
        background: #9e9e9e;
        height: 20px;
        width: 978px;
    }
    br{
        clear: left;
    }​
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $('.action').click(function() {          
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var content = $('.content[name=' + name + ']');
            $('.content').not(content).hide('fast');
            content.slideToggle('fast');
        });
    });​

    </script>
     </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container"><ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="action" name="summer">summer</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="action" name="winter">winter</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="action" name="weather">weather</a>
        </li>
        </ul></div><br>
        <div class="content" name="summer">
            <a href="link">june</a>
            <a href="link">july</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content" name="winter">
                <a href="link">november</a>
                <a href="link">december</a>
            </div>
        <div class="content" name="weather">
                <a href="link">rain</a>
                <a href="link">sun</a>
        </div>

        <div id="div"></div>​


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is happening that do or dont expect to be happening?

Comment: when i click on the link a dropdown menu should appear. But nothing is happening.

Comment: Seems to work in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/pE7RW/

Comment: I got the code from jfiddle. when i transfer it over to html it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

try SuperFish => http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Style and script tags should be inside your head tag. (though some people put all scripts just before the closing body tag)

Without having a doctype weird things can happen. add "<!doctype html>" before your opening html tag.

Comment: I added the doctype and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you've got a double forward slash in:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

unless you mean something like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: http:// explicitly requests non-encrypted transmission while https:// requests the opposite. // is implicit to whatever the current connection is.

See here: //stackoverflow.com/questions/4659345/ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and there's an illegal character at line 42, after the second "});". I deleted this and it's working.